# Modify input fields with JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've got the following code :

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, function(data) {
   $('input#titre').val(data.titre);
   $('input#content').val(data.content);
});
```

`docsel.php` returns a JSON encoded array with `titre` and `content` and their values.
I checked that returned data is correct.

Now I'd like to modify input fields with results, but my code doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

Here is the data (i put auteur and not content to simplify) :

```
"[{"titre":"Dipt\u00e9rosodomanie et t\u00e9trapilotomie radiaire, pourquoi ?","auteur":"Alex"}]"
```

I modified my code like this :

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, showResult(data));
                });
            });

function showResult(data)

{
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);

  var titre = obj.titre[0];

$('#titre').val(titre);
```

but it doesn't work, I mean input field "titre" is not modified. Please take into account that I am an absolute beginner in JQuery / Php .

Comment: Not an answer, but you don't need to select the input, because `id` is always unique: `$('#titre')`. Or are you saying it isn't unique?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  That doesn't help us at all.

Comment: Did you edit Mick Hansen's answer with your code?  Don't do that.  Add it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, function(data) {
   $('input#titre').val(data.titre);
   $('input#content').val(data.content);
}, "json");
```

I believe you do need to specify when you want the returned data to be parsed as JSON.
You could test the data returned via `console.log(data)` if it outputs a string and not an object, it hasn't been parsed.

Comment: +1, this is (probably) the issue, I've done this myself way too many times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, showResult(data));
```

This runs the `showResult` function, and then uses its return value (`undefined`) as the callback.

It should be:

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, function(data){
  showResult(data)
});
```

Or, better yet:

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, showResult);
```

You don't need to use `JSON.parse` yourself.  Just pass `'json'` to `$.post` and it'll do that for you.

```
$.post("docsel.php", {id : id}, showResult, 'json');

function showResult(data){
    var titre = data[0].titre; // Data is an array of objects
    $('#titre').val(titre);
}
```

Comment: It works ! For some unknown reason, the syntax : ` $('#titre').val(titre); `  doesn't work for me. I tried `$('[name=titre]').val(titre);` and my problem was solved. Thank you very much for your help.